# Precisely Adjusting Position of Multiple Screens

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have three montiors. Two are at different heights relative to the main screen.
In Windows display properties you can drag the monitors up and down to move them about, but there is a 'snap' action- so I can't precisely adjust the position of the screen,

e.g the default position is 1680, 150, as soon as I drag it down it jumps to 1680, 255. I need a value between 150 and 255!

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: The position of what exactly?  I am confused by the description of your problem.

Comment: Picture added- look at the numbers on screen 3. If you drag the screen up and down, it 'snaps' to a position.